# open_ai textclassification finetuning

Tags: python, openai-api, text-classification

'''openai.datalib.MissingDependencyError:
OpenAI error:

```
missing `pandas`
```

This feature requires additional dependencies:

```
$ pip install openai[datalib]'''
```

I tried "pip install openai[datalib]" in aws segmaker  still getting same error